# Tabbed Accounts and Salesforce1 - Must they not work together?

Tags: visualforce, page-layout

With a long chatter feed your Account page may inolve lots of scrolling, or hiding the feed (defeating the point of having it!)

To the rescure, this old gem, tabbed Accounts! http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Tabbed_Accounts_in_30_seconds

The BIG FAIL - mine or Salesforce's ?
Can I have my Salesforce1 users see the default layout, not this VF page? 
I am missing how to make this work on both platforms - please help! 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an Idea Exchange post for grappling with this glaring hole:
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kxyTAAQ&sort=2

To work around this, make sure the VF page is NOT enabled for Salesforce Mobile etc. Then you'll get the default page in your sf1 app.